# History of shared web pages in Safari

Tags: safari, privacy, history

I shared a web page via Safari (8 on Yosemite) once. Now the last recipient shows up in the menu. How can I delete it from there? See picture for how it looks.

[image: Share menu on Safari including the last recipient]

Comment: Try to clear the history of your browser.

Comment: I would like to keep my history. Is there a way to re-import it after clearing?

Comment: 1. Select "Macintosh HD", click "Users".
2. Double-click your user name.
3. Double-click "Library".
4. Click the "Safari" folder.
5. The "History.plist" is the Safari history of documents, back up it.
6. Then after cleaning, move this file into this folder back.

Comment: Safari history is no longer kept in ~/Library/Safari/History.plist. Also, http://support.apple.com/kb/PH19215?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US does not list Sharing recipients as items cleared when you "Clear History and Website Data..."

Comment: Re-importing my history worked! But the last recipient was not deleted in the cleaning process as pseudon said.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be there, who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a long time ago, but I found out how to delete the recently shared items and haven't answered yet. So here is how it goes:

Delete the plist file:

Old: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sharekit.recents.plist

New: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.extensions.ShareMenu.plist

I forgot when exactly macOS changed the file location, and maybe both file are present after an upgrade.

You can use `plutil -convert xml1 <filename>` to convert the plist into a human-readable XML format if you want to inspect it.